# User Provided OS on Google Cloud?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I want to use Google Cloud as IaaS, mainly because they accept debt card not credit card,
I'm trying to automate some tasks but mainly on windows because my apps crash with wine.
Would you guide me with the below?
What is the user provided OS on google cloud IaaS?
Where can I find tutorial about it or how to do it?
Can I provide a windows DVD?

Kindly check the link below.
https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator/

Comment: @boraseoksoon Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Compute Engine does not currently support uploading custom Windows images.

Comment: Thanks for replying